# How to loop through two lists with different lengths simultaneously in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I use Python. I created two lists with different lengths:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I want to print out pairs of numbers and letters as

```
"1a 2b 3c 4a 5b 1c 2a 3b 4c 5a 1b 2c 3a 4b 5c"`
```

to loop through both lists simultaneously.

The following nested for loop prints out pairs as

```
"1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 3a 3b 3c 4a 4b 4c 5a 5b 5c"`
```

which is not what I want:

```
for num in list_1:
    for letter in list_2:
        print(num, letter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `zip` and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> for _, x, y in zip(range(len(a) * len(b)), cycle(a), cycle(b)):
...     print(x, y)
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 a
5 b
1 c
2 a
3 b
4 c
5 a
1 b
2 c
3 a
4 b
5 c
```

Alternatively, using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead of `range`:

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice

for x, y in islice(zip(cycle(a), cycle(b)), len(a) * len(b)):
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for x, y in zip(a * len(b), b * len(a)):
        print(x, y)


1 a
2 b
3 c
4 a
5 b
1 c
2 a
3 b
4 c
5 a
1 b
2 c
3 a
4 b
5 c
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not going to explain something obvious unless asked to. Why are you not complaining about the other answer the same way? It also doesn't explain anything, and it's equally "complicated" (if not more).

Comment: The commentary in the link helps to explain it as do a number of other meta questions on the same subject. Well documented answers tend to gather more upvotes, but that's up to you.

Comment: @theTinMan Um, how did my new comment get deleted? Was that you?

Comment: It had to be a moderator as they're the only ones with that privilege.